Looker Studio connector caching names & descriptions for metric fields
What's the problem?
We're building a looker Studio connector. It uses BigQuery as the base, but then also uses the getSchema in order to add custom fields on top of this.
Our problem is with the metric fields.
The dimensions fields change name/description everytime we change it.
fieldConfig = fields
          .newDimension()
          .setId("country")
          .setName("Country")
          .setType(types.TEXT);

However anything with a formula aggregation doesnt:
fieldConfig = fields
          .newMetric()
          .setId(`sessions_sum`)
          .setName(Sessions)
          .setType(types.NUMBER)
          .setFormula(`sum(sessions)`)
          .setAggregation(aggregations.AUTO);

When you change the name it doesnt change.
Refreshing the fields, going back to re-configure the connector does nothing.
If you cycle the formula i.e.:
.setFormula(`sum(sessions + 0)`)
Looker Studio will see the field has changed when refreshing fields and notification says field has changed and shows the new field name.
However the interface/resource still doesn't even after all of that.
How does this cache work? Is there any way at all to clear it consistently?

I think that might be a "deploy" issue -- every time you deploy it gives you a "new" connector. Does that make sense?

Possibly? It's inconsistent tho right? Because the ID's are the same so I guess iif it was new it then reties all the fields ( as i don't have to reselect them).
But then it refreshes all the other fields except metrics with formulas. Basically everything else refreshes whenever you re-call the function (getData, getSchema) etc. it's just metric fields with formulas which don't change.
